$H^2$ (complement of closed unbounded connected)
Let $C$ be a closed connected unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is it true that $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus C)=0$ (de Rham cohomology group here)? It seems that this is true, arguing from the de Rham theorem - every closed surface in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus C$ should be a boundary of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus C$, otherwise, $C$ would not be connected (maybe some form of Jordan separation theorem should also be invoked here).
However, is there somewhat more direct approach to viewing this?
On the other hand, it is clear that if $C$ is bounded, then $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus C)\ne 0$.
Connectedness in the original questions seems unnecesary, as long as each connected component of $C$ is unbounded.

Hint: First use Alexander duality to prove that $H_2(R^3\setminus C)=0$.

Let me use sheaf machinery, and the sheafy version of Poincare' duality, offered in Iversen's "Cohomology of sheaves". I don't follow your argument - I'm not sure what version of De Rham's theorem you're referring to: you seem to be using the idea that in low dimensions, singular cohomology can be represented not just by chains but by surfaces, but I don't know a precise statement.
Let us note that $K=\overline{C}\subset S^3$ is compact and connected, and equal to $C\cup\{\infty\}$ as $C$ is unbounded, and $U:=S^3\setminus K=\Bbb R^3\setminus C$ is a $3$-manifold without boundary, cohomologically oriented over any field whatsoever, in particular $k=\Bbb R$, so that $H^2(U)\cong H^1_c(U)^\ast$. We want to show $H^1_c(U)=0$; in light of the short exact sequence of sheaves $0\to\underline{\Bbb R}_U\to\underline{\Bbb R}\to\underline{\Bbb R}_K\to0$ on $S^3$ we derive: $$H^0_c(S^3)\to H^0_c(K)\to H^1_c(U)\to 0\cong H^1_c(S^3)$$And since $K$ is connected, and compact, the first map is identified with a map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which is nonzero, since the restriction of a constant nonzero function on $S^3$ to $K$ of course yields something nonzero, so this first map is an isomorphism; it follows that $H^1_c(U)\cong0$ so $H^2(U)\cong0$ as well.
Here, all of the adjectives: closed, unbounded, and connected, were used. But your suspicion about the sense in which connectedness is important is correct (we only need $K$ connected) - we actually see that if $C$ has $n$ bounded components, with all other adjectives maintained, for $n$ a finite integer, then $H^2(\Bbb R^3\setminus C;\Bbb R)\cong\Bbb R^n$.

Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I have not studied sheafs yet, though this is one of the subjects I am considering next. I accept your answer, but encourage other people to answer or comment if they have different ideas. As for my idea, I did not mean it to be rigorous in any way, just a guiding intuition. Still, regarding your question of representability of homology classes by submanifolds, I think the first point of the accepted answer at - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21171/when-is-a-homology-class-represented-by-a-submanifold is relevant.

@Jeremiah Hi, welcome to the site. I just used sheaves to derive the long exact sequence in compactly supported cohomology, $H^\bullet_c(S^3)\to H^\bullet_c(K)\to H^\bullet_c(U)\to H^\bullet_c(S^3)[+1]$, and compactly supported sheaf cohomology and compactly supported singular cohomology agree for manifolds (and in fact a wider class of spaces, though this does not seem to be carefully written down anywhere; for instance, I would have to think quite hard about whether or not $H^\bullet_c(K)$ is the same in the sheafy and singular senses, as it is not a manifold).

I also used the version of Poincare duality which I learned from sheaf theory, but Poincare duality can mean so many things. There are probably classical references in singular cohomology which demonstrate $H^k(M;\Bbb F)\cong H^{n-k}_c(M;\Bbb F)^\ast$ for boundaryless, oriented $n$-manifolds $M$ and fields $\Bbb F$. The long exact sequence in cohomology that I wrote also, probably, could be proven using singular methods

Thank you very much for your clarifications! I will also find the book you mentioned, to see if it would be helpful for introducing me to the subject.
